# Determine Client version of Application on Startup

Tags: c#, version

Problem:

We have a C# application, .Net 3.5 which is updated manually on client computers. Don't even ask, we can't do the one-click deploys.

When a new build is created and a client has not been updated, I would like to alert the client (on start-up) that the application is out of date and a new build must be obtained before proceeding.

I am interested in what approaches others may have used to solve the same problem (restricting clients from using old builds)

Thanks - Glenn

Comment: Is it a client server application? DO you connect to server before login?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a web service which will return the current application version. The service must be installed where it is available for the clients to call.

Then you need to add a call to the service and check the running application version against the version from the service.

Comment: Interesting approach - I'm going to review this option in addition to just validating the assembly. The problem with simply validating the assembly is that you don't yet have something to compare it to. Thanks

Comment: Alexander - I will look at combining the web service approach with the client something validation. One issue is that we track the client build # which is provided by TeamCity. Thanks for the ideas. Glenn

Answer (score 0):

our application is connected to a DB and we ensure at the start up of the application that the version of the App matches the version recorded in the DB. If it does not match a message is displayed to the user. If your app does not connect to a DB I suppose it could talk to a WCF service to get whatever the latest version is. I have seen people simply retrieving a file from a shared drive and reading the value from it. This requires the shared UNC path to be available from all users which is not always convenient.

Comment: Thanks Michael - I have used that approach before too. In this case I would like to validate the client even before a connection to the target database occurs. Glenn

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ClickOnce to distribute your application? If yes, you can specify minimum version required before publish it.

If no, you can manage versions of executable files and check it on startup. Something like:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
string version = fvi.FileVersion;
```

Comment: I called it one-click in my description, but no, ClickOnce or one-click is not used.

Comment: ClickOnce is not only to deploy the app, it is more for distribution to end-users.